# team foundation server sharepoint web site access permissions

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, project, sharepointfoundation2010

Please help. 
Am newbie and have hit a snag with TFS and Sharepoint combo. Come from old school where in IIS you right click and set permissions of Web Site, and now I can't find the sharepoint sites in IIS 7 to actually give myself permissions. 
When opening the localhost/ sites/ project in IE, i get an Error: Access Denied.
This is the sharepoint site that was set up by TFS when I added a project in Visual Studio 2010 to my TFS ProjectCollection. 
How do I get access to the web site?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Permission is not give to the SP sites directly from IIS.

If you are or you know the SP Site collection administrator, ask them to give you the appropriate access to the SP site you are requesting. Otherwise, if there are no site collection administrators then go a level higher to the SP farm administrator, ask the farm admin to grant make you the site collection administrator for the SP Site collection you are trying to access. The team project site is located under a site collection.

From there you can give other users access to the appropriate SP resources using Site Actions > Site Permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It definitely pointed me in the right direction.:-) I had to go into the Central Administration and into Site Collection Administrators, and click on site Collection url,change site collection, click on the specific  url, click ok, and set myself as the primary site collection administrator, and then click ok again. :-)

Comment: in this case it was taking ownership of a site collection, that fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should be given the permissions inside SharePoint by site collection administrator.

Site collection admin should navigate to localhost/sites/{tfscollection}/{tfsproject}, click Site settings and then People and groups link.

From there, you need to be added to the site and given the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really nice utility that makes it easy to view/edit permissions on TFS, SharePoint and Report Server at the same time.

http://tfsadmin.codeplex.com/